# How to concatenate conditions

Tags: ruby

Is there a more elegant way to write this in Ruby?

```
def tutorial_completed?
  people.any? && projects.any? && invoices.any?
end
```

Comment: depending on the definition of *elegant*, you could use `and` instead of `&&` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def tutorial_completed?
  [people, projects, invoices].all?(&:any?)
end
```

Comment: Just curious, isn't the original version more readeable than this?

Comment: I don't particularly like this form as it involves creation of an intermediate array. I also think it's less readable, though that's a matter of opinion.

Comment: Yes, a matter of opinion. Since OP was not happy with his version, this is a good alternative proposal. +1

Comment: OK, actually you convinced me to stick with my initial version. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Chris: it creates an intermediate array... of size 3. I think modern computers can handle this :-) It'd be somewhat more declarative if we had other abstractions at hand, all+any sounds cacophonic. For example this can be read out loud: `[people, projects, invoices].all?(&:not_empty?)`.

Comment: @tokland You'd be surprised at how frequently you find that kind of thing used in things like DB drivers. Avoiding it is a substantial kindness to the GC in high-frequency code.

Comment: @ChrisHeald. That's true, but well, we are in a `Tutorial#completed?` method, I don't think we should be worrying about being called too often. First let's write the most declarative code we can, and only when we confirm a particular piece of code is slowing the app down, then write it as ugly as necessary. That said, the original code was perfectly ok (if we had 10 arrays to check maybe it wouldn't be so ok).

Comment: Completely agreed, it's fine in this instance. I just wanted to point out that while functionally equivalent, they don't do exactly the same thing. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do as below :

```
[people,projects,invoices].all? {|i| i.any? }
```

**Demo**

```
 people = [true]
 projects = [false]
 invoices = [true,12]
 [people,projects,invoices].all? {|i| i.any? }
 # => false
```